# Exporting Vertex Groups gltf

Tags: modeling, vertex-groups, gltf

This is my very first blender and three js project so I am really lost. I am trying to export my model from blender as a gltf file but when i load it into https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ the sprinkles on the icing are missing no matter how I change the export properties. I think its got to do with the vertex group or the modifiers?
[image]

Comment: You'll need to apply the modifiers.  The glTF format stores mesh data in ready-to-render form. It won't ask a ThreeJS client to process a bunch of Blender geometry nodes on the client side, you have to apply those in Blender prior to or during conversion.  There's an "apply modifiers" checkbox in the exporter properties panel.

Comment: Hi emackey! thakns your your suggestion, I have tried to select that exporter property but it doesnt seem to work. It still disappears when I export it. When I try to apply the modifiers in blender it disappears too.

Comment: Ah, in that case, I would ask a new question on this site.  Give a screenshot and an example blend if possible, and say something like "When I click apply modifiers, it disappears" explaining that you need to be able to realize this model into final geometry with all modifiers applied.